# How to make UL in div with horizontal scroll have full width

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` in a `div` which has a horizontal scroll applied.  The div is 180px and the items in the `ul` are bigger than this.

This problem I've got is that the `ul` and `li`'s don't extend to their natural width, instead they have the width of the element with the scroll applied.  This means that if you apply a background colour to the list items it doesn't cover the whole element.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```css
div.wrapper {
      float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <ul>
    <li><h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k qwroksal wasdlk was</h3></li>
    <li><h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k wasdlk was</h3></li>
    <li><h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k qwroksal wasdlk was</h3></li>
    <li><h3>sdf df sdijdsf r wafl;k qwroksal wasdlk was</h3></li>
    <li><h3>sdf df sdijr d  df dfswe ef ewf wafl;k qwroksal wdsfdsfasdlk was</h3></li>
    <li><h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k wasdlk was</h3></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you, the issues is with child div of `.wrapper`, set `float:left` to it.

```css
div.wrapper {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
}
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  float: left;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k qwroksal wasdlk was</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k wasdlk was</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k qwroksal wasdlk was</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>sdf df sdijdsf r wafl;k qwroksal wasdlk was</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>sdf df sdijr d  df dfswe ef ewf wafl;k qwroksal wdsfdsfasdlk was</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>sdf df sdijr wafl;k wasdlk was</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will remove the scrolling though so it's not a solution

Comment: Check `snippet` again, @Chris

Comment: That's solves it, so adding `float: left` fixes it, thanks.  You should make it clearer from your answer what the fix is for anyone coming to this in the future

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention

Answer (score 1):

You could apply an intrinsic width value `width: min-content;` to the `li`, like [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kytf2muf/1/)

However, you'd need to check cross-browser support against your specific requirements.

Another way ([example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kytf2muf/3/)) might be to use `display: inline-block;` on the `li` elements? I've added some margin to space them out again since they'll adopt `line-height`.

Comment: Thank you, this kinds of works but it means that the `li`'s are different widths

Comment: I would imagine if you want full browser support you're best looking at a js solution with this as well. This seems to be working great.

Comment: @Chris I've updated the answer above with another possible approach.

Answer (score -1):

By just adding `display: inline-block;` to the `div` next to `.wrapper` should solve the problem.